# how to sync an exchange attribute to on premise AD Object

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a few users with custom attributes.
I want to copy the value of these custom attributes and add them to the users ExtensionAttribute property in their AD object.

So far I have tried :

```
 $CustomAttr1 = get-mailbox  $upn | Select CustomAttribute1
 Set-ADUser -server Server -identity Identity -Add @{ExtensionAttribute1=$CustomAttr1}
```

The end result is just "@{$CustomAttribute1}" in the actual AD attribute.

How can I extract the string value of 'CustomAttribute1' from Exchange and pass it into AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Select` will filter the resulting object to a have a single property, `CustomAttribute1`. So when you need to set the value, you have to reference the property `$CustomAttr1.CustomAttribute1` to get the value:

```
$CustomAttr1 = get-mailbox  $upn | Select CustomAttribute1
Set-ADUser -server Server -identity Identity -Add @{ExtensionAttribute1=$CustomAttr1.CustomAttribute1}
```

Comment: Basically, we want to start to sync our AD objects with Azure AD using AAD-Connect so we want the AD objects to be correct before adding users to the AAD-Connect_Enabled group which then syncs their AD object properties to Azure. we need users AD objects to be correct before we do this. hence why I want to pull data from Exchange (which is correct) to our AD account so that when users are added to the AAD-Connect group, their data syncs upto Azure. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Ah I see. You simply have to reference the property `$CustomAttr1.CustomAttribute1` when setting the attribute. See Edit above

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the help I needed. I cant believe it was just a ".customattribute1" that I was missing all along!!!

Comment: Or use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute1`